# Using CSV file with coordinates and multiple attributes to extract interpolated values for different set of coordinates in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, csv, interpolation, multi-values

I have a .cvs file of 501 rows that correspond to 500 coordinate points, with each row consisting of latitude, longitude for a single location, followed by a list of about 100 weather attributes (precipitation, temp, etc. for various time periods). The first row is a header specifying all these variable. Together, the 500 points make a fairly regular grid that covers Uganda.

I would like to use these 500 points to interpolate (natural neighbor) and extract values for all 100+ weather attributes for a list of 1000 points that represent the locations of surveyed households in Uganda (also in csv format, with a household identifier). The end product that I would like to generate is a new csv (or excel file) with each row as lat, long, household identifier, and the 100 weather variables (basically the original csv but for a different set of coordinates).

Which sequence of tools can I use to accomplish this in ArcGIS? I have access to Spatial Analyst.

So far I have tried a few things but haven't been able to complete the full process with success (I only mention the steps that in hindsight seem most promising):

First, I converted the original csv of weather attributes to an excel table and then used the *Excel to Table* tool. This successfully generated a table that preserves the lat, long, weather attributes, and generates an ObjectID. From here, I next tried to use the *Point to Raster* tool (thinking I might be able to make a multiband raster from the table, but this step might not be needed), but this only allows the conversion of a single field at a time. Then I thought I would skip conversion to a raster, and directly applied the *Natural Neighbor* tool to the table, and this does successfully generate the interpolated raster to cover the entire geographic area of interest, but it also only allows a single field/attribute at a time.

*Is there a tool that will allow me to do more than one attribute at a time, or is a loop over all the attribute names my best option?*

My hope is to get the data into a form from which I can apply the *Extract Multi Values to Points* tool. (I am happy to use Shift + Control + C to simply copy the resulting table at the end.)

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have made edits to describe the tools I have tried to apply so far. @underdark

Comment: A cell in a raster can only hold one value. So if you want to convert your locations and their associated weather attributes into rasters you will have to run the Natural Neighbour tool each time for each attribute. Modelbuilder with an iterator would automate all this for you. So have a look at the help file about modelbuilder and geoprocessing.